# Maven deploy plugin override error?

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I am trying to override deploy plugin for maven and get the following error on some of my projects but not others:

`Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.6:deploy failed: Cannot add two different pieces of metadata for:`

Here is my plugin definition:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-deploy</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <pomFile>target/modified-pom-replacePomPlaceholder/modified-pom/pom.xml</pomFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also tried this to same effect:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <pomFile>target/modified-pom-replacePomPlaceholder/modified-pom/pom.xml</pomFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any idea why it fails sometimes?

Comment: If only thing you're trying to override is alternative pom file, you should probably remove `<executions>` at all and just put `<configuration>` below plugin coordinates.

Comment: Same error. I think it may have something to do with the flexmojos-maven-plugin in that project.

Comment: You can try commenting it out and checking if it helps. You can also try to upgrade/downgrade `deploy` plugin version by specifying it explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Don't override 'default-deploy'. Deactivate it and write your own:

```
<execution>
  <id>default-deploy</id>
  <phase>none</phase>
</execution>
<execution>
  <id>my-deploy</id>
  <phase>deploy</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>deploy</goal>
  </goals>
  ...
</execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late, but here my assumption:

run maven with debug output on, e.g. *mvn clean deploy -X*, then check the debug output, especially the following two lines:

```
    [DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = /home/rotscher/projects/localswap/localswap-web/target/pom.xml
    [DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: ch.rotscher.localswap:localswap-web:1 @ /home/rotscher/projects/localswap/localswap-web/target/pom.xml
```

The paths should be equals (according to java.io.File.equals).
So, I guess your solution could be to configure the path of *pomFile* with *${basedir}*:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
          <pomFile>${basedir}/target/modified-pom-replacePomPlaceholder/modified-pom/pom.xml</pomFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```